# My Flutter app showing white screen in release apk

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle, build.gradle, flutter-video-player

My flutter app runs fine on debug mode but when i create release apk its stuck on white screen.

Main Screen
[image: Main Screen]

My Flutter app showing white screen in release apk
[image: My Flutter app showing white screen in release apk]

Comment: Does it show any logs that indicate an error?

Comment: You should at least share some basic code and some logs to the question.

Answer (score 2):

This happens due to error in code, usually while running app on debug mode, these error appear on console but doesn't break  the app. Hence you app might be working fine in `debug` mode and not in `release` mode.

I'll suggest to run the app in debug mode and try to fix the errors that pop up in console, you can even use `devtools` by flutter to pinpoint the issue

Feel free to share your code and console output so that we could look into the issue too and help you figure out.

Answer (score 1):

It is because in debug mode some issue gets logged in the terminal but it does not work in a release. to solve it properly check the logs in debug mode and it will show you some error generally a UI error related to expanded stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem

this is my first screen https://i.stack.imgur.com/39B7t.jpg

this is my screen screen photo of debug apk https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lbc23.jpg

This is my second screen photo of release apk https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCvRY.jpg

Having this problem after updating my flutter doctor result

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)

[√] Chrome - develop for the web

[√] Android Studio (version 2021.2)

[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2021.2)

[√] VS Code (version 1.68.1)

[√] Connected device (4 available)

[√] HTTP Host Availability

thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Set the `extendBody` of the `Scaffold` to true. Might be the same problem as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74627906/flutter-app-ui-disappears-after-restarting-once-in-apk-release/74632494#74632494)

Answer (score 0):

Just run `flutter doctor` command. It will list out some issues that freezes the app. Mine issue was I haven't accepted android sdk license after I accept the license it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

There might be some Expanded widgets in your widgets which may not be inside Column,Row,Flex widgets.
Expanded can only work inside of this column, row, flex.

I once faced the same issue and resolved it by removing expanded.

This is like works fine in debug and shows error in release mode.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this issue and the problem was that widget bindings were not properly initialized. And I added this code in `main()` method and it resolved the issue:

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
```