# Flutter app UI disappears after restarting once in apk release

Tags: flutter, apk, release, flutter-getx

After downloading the app through the apk release, in the first time, it works normally. But once you close the app and open it again, the ui elements disappears. It has a very strange behavior, if I restart the device, it works in the first time the app is open (after the restart), and after closing it, it doens't work again.

This only happens in the release version, debugging works as expected.

[image: Screen opening the app for the first time, or after restarting the device] [image: Screen after restarting the app]

I am using `Getx`, I don't see a relation since I have already develop other apps with this structure. This is the code of the first page loaded.

```
return Container(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: Get.width, minHeight: Get.height),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        image: DecorationImage(
          opacity: 0.35,
          repeat: ImageRepeat.repeat,
          image: AssetImage(AppConstants.assets.background_image),
        ),
      ),
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        body: Container(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  width: Get.width,
                  height: Get.height * 0.45,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 80.0),
                      child: SizedBox(
                        width: Get.width * 0.8,
                        height: Get.height * 0.3,
                        child: Image.asset(AppConstants.assets.logo_image),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: Get.height * 0.55,
                  child: TabBarView(
                    controller: controller.tabController,
                    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    children: [
                      TelephoneTab(),
                      CodeTab(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

I have tried removing the background image by removing the Container before the `Scaffold` entirely, removing every element in the UI and adding just a small button in the middle. Updating my kotlin.

Tried running with `flutter run --release`. No logs.

May be the same thing as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72667670/my-flutter-app-showing-white-screen-in-release-apk).

Flutter doctor is fine.

Comment: Since this problem just occurs on release there are no logs

Comment: apk -> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_Pl_tK9BgRew00Cu3jWzIYCgBGqNiYIX/view?usp=share_link

Comment: have you checked the release version of apk, i.e. `flutter build apk --release`, or confirm the given link of apk created with release flag or not ? Also, you can check the logs while running in release mode using `flutter run --release`

Comment: The version defined in the `pubspec` is `version: 1.0.0+1` I am not sure if that is what you meant. I have built the apk using the command `flutter build apk --release` as you said.

Comment: Just tried running with `flutter run --release` nothing changed. No logs.

There were logs about a google font that wasn't loading properly, but I removed it from the code and ran it again.

Comment: try to uninstall the whole app from the device, since it could stay the debug version, then install it again, don't try to install a release as an update of the debug version

Comment: I have tried this, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be something related to the `Scaffold` and the `Container` with the background image. Elements outside the `Scaffold` were drawn as usual.

I changed the first page of the app in order to go directly to the `HomePage` and it worked fine, even logging out to the `LoginPage`.

Then I tried creating a `SplashPage` before the `LoginPage`, initially, I used the same structure with the `Container`, `BoxDecoration`, and `Scaffold`. The problem was happening again, but this time in the `SplashPage`, everything inside the Scaffold was invisible with the same behavior as mentioned above.

After that, I simply define the `extendBody` as true in the `Scaffold` of the `SplashPage` and the problem stopped occurring.

I don't exactly understand what this changes. Feel free to add an explanation to this answer.